# Non-existence of a PATH in Neo4j and Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the best way to formulate:

RETURN node n if there is no path like (:Id)-->(n). Is OPTIONAL MATCH the best we can hope for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you do have a couple options, I recommend using a label on `n`, otherwise, this will require a scan and expansion of all nodes in your graph, which is likely to be an expensive operation.

That said, this query might be shorter and easier to work with:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (:Id)-->(n)
RETURN n
```